# How to change scale of spawning prefabs depending on score?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### **UPDATE**

Allow me to organize this question in another way. Forgive me, my previous code may have been confusing and I have made a few changes.

As the player collides with the objects being spawned, the objects being spawned are destroyed and the player gains a point. When the player earns a certain amount of points (in this case lets say 3) the objects being spawned will begin to get smaller.

**The Main Goal**

The player gains 3 points, the objects being spawned scale down by a small fraction (in this case 0.1). Repeat this process every time the player gets 3 points.

**Current Logic**

*-Game Manager-*

First let me show you what is keeping track of the score inside the Game Manager.

```
//Singleton
public static GameManager gameManager { get; private set; }

//if repeat score = 4 reset to 0 to repeat the process  
public int repeatScoreGoal = 4;

[HideInInspector]
public int repeatScore = 0;

//access this method in another script to increase repeatScore value
//when they player collides and destroys object
public void RepeatScore()
{
    repeatScore += 1;

    if (repeatScore >= repeatScoreGoal)
    {
        repeatScore = 0;
    }
}
```

*-Collision Detection to Increase Score-*

Here is the method on the script attached to the player to increase score when the player collides with the object.

```
  private const string tagDestructible = "Destructible";

  private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == tagDestructible)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == tagDestructible)
        {
            GameManager.gameManager.RepeatScore();
        }
        
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
```

*-Prefab Scale Script Attached to Prefab-*

This time instead of scaling the object in the "ObjectSpawner" script, I created a simple script to attach to the prefab itself so each prefab can have its own unique scale. This allows me to not have to recreate the empty game object that the "ObjectSpawner" script is attached to when I want to spawn different objects. The scale would change to a unique value for each prefab which will come in handy later down the road.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PrefabScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int recScore = 3;
    private int currentScore;

    private bool objectScale = false;

void Update()
{
    //variable referencing to singleton
    currentScore = GameManager.gameManager.repeatScore;
    
    //if reapeatSore in Game Manager = recScore, scale object
    if (currentScore >= recScore && objectScale == false)
    {
        objectScale = true;

        if (objectScale == true)
        {
            gameObject.transform.localScale += new Vector3(-0.1f, -0.1f, 
            -0.1f);
        }

        if (currentScore == 0)
        {
            objectScale = false;
        }
    }
}
```

*-Object Spawner Script Attached to Empty Game Object Spawning Prefabs-*

Now lets see the "ObjectSpawner" script that is attached to an empty game object spawning the prefabs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float[] percentages;

    public GameObject[] prefab;

    public float spawnRate = 1f;
    public float minHeight = -1f;
    public float maxHeight = 1f;

    public int recScore = 3;
    private int currentScore;
    
    //ignore these variables, view notes in update method for more info
    /*
    private bool spawnPointPosition = false;
    private float resetSpawnPoint;
    */

private void OnEnable()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(Spawn), spawnRate, spawnRate);
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    CancelInvoke(nameof(Spawn));
}

private void Spawn()
{
    GameObject objects = Instantiate(prefab[GetRandomSpawn()], 
    transform.position,
    Quaternion.identity);
    objects.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, 
    maxHeight);
    objects.transform.SetParent(transform);
}

private int GetRandomSpawn()
{
    float random = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    float numForAdding = 0;
    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < percentages.Length; i++)
    {
        total += percentages[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < prefab.Length; i++)
    {
        if (percentages[i] / total + numForAdding >= random)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            numForAdding += percentages[i] / total;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

private void Update()
{
    /*I left this singleton reference here just incase we need it for 
      the current problem we are trying to sovle */
    currentScore = GameManager.gameManager.repeatScore;
    
    

    /*ignore this below, this is adjusting the x position of the 
      empty game object that is spawning the prefabs and does not relate 
      to the scaling of the prefabs*/
    /*

    resetSpawnPoint = GameManager.gameManager.score;

    if (currentScore >= recScore && spawnPointPosition == false)
    {
        spawnPointPosition = true;

        if (spawnPointPosition == true)
        {
            gameObject.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }

    }

    if (currentScore == 0)
    {
        spawnPointPosition = false;
    }

    if (resetSpawnPoint == 0)
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(20f, 0f, 0f);
    }
    */
}
```

}

### **Current Results**

With this current setup, When the player earns the required score (in this case we are still just going to say 3) the objects that are currently spawned will scale.

However, the objects that spawn after that scale are the original size of the prefab until the player hits the required score again. I'm looking for a way to retain that scale with the newly spawned objects and for this entire process to repeat every time the player gets 3 points.

*What is currently happening:*

The game starts, the objects scale is 1. The player destroys 3 objects earning 3 points. All objects on the screen scale to 0.9. All objects being spawned after are back to scale 1.

*I am looking for:*

The game starts, the player gets 3 points, objects on screen scale to 0.9. Newly spawned objects are also scale 0.9. the player gets another 3 points. objects on screen are now scale to 0.8. Newly spawned objects are also scaled to 0.8. The process just keeps going.

I hope this clears some things up! Thank you all so much for your time and input!

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float[] percentages;

    public GameObject[] prefab;

    public float spawnRate = 1f;
    public float minHeight = -1f;
    public float maxHeight = 1f;

    public int recScore = 3;
    private int currentScore;

    private List<GameObject> spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>(); // Store references to the spawned objects
    private List<GameObject> newSpawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>(); // Store references to newly spawned objects
    private bool isScaling = false; // Flag to track if scaling is in progress
    private bool isNewSpawnScaled = false; // Flag to track if newly spawned objects have been scaled

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(Spawn), spawnRate, spawnRate);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        CancelInvoke(nameof(Spawn));
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        GameObject spawnedObject = Instantiate(prefab[GetRandomSpawn()], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        spawnedObject.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
        spawnedObject.transform.SetParent(transform);

        spawnedObjects.Add(spawnedObject);
        newSpawnedObjects.Add(spawnedObject);

        if (currentScore >= recScore && !isScaling && !isNewSpawnScaled)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleSpawnedObjects());
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetScaleFactor()
    {
        // Define the scaling factor you want to apply
        Vector3 scaleFactor = new Vector3(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
        return scaleFactor;
    }

    private int GetRandomSpawn()
    {
        // ... (your existing code)
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleSpawnedObjects()
    {
        isScaling = true;

        Vector3 scaleFactor = GetScaleFactor();

        foreach (GameObject spawnedObject in spawnedObjects)
        {
            if (spawnedObject != null)
            {
                spawnedObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(spawnedObject.transform.localScale, scaleFactor);
                yield return null; // Wait for the next frame before scaling the next object
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject newSpawnedObject in newSpawnedObjects)
        {
            if (newSpawnedObject != null)
            {
                newSpawnedObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(newSpawnedObject.transform.localScale, scaleFactor);
            }
        }

        isNewSpawnScaled = true; // Set the flag to indicate that newly spawned objects have been scaled
        isScaling = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        currentScore = GameManager.gameManager.repeatScore;

        if (currentScore >= recScore && !isScaling && !isNewSpawnScaled)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleSpawnedObjects());
        }

        if (currentScore == 0)
        {
            isNewSpawnScaled = false; // Reset the flag when the score reaches 0
            newSpawnedObjects.Clear(); // Clear the list of newly spawned objects
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: When the `currentScore` is greater than or equal to the `recScore`, the `ScaleSpawnedObjects` method is called to scale the existing objects.
When the `currentScore` is less than the `recScore`, the `ResetScale` method is called to reset the scale of the objects to the initial scale.

Comment: Hey mike, thanks for the quick reply! however I'm struggling to understand some of your answer. If you look at my "private void Spawn()" there is already a variable for the game object that is being instantiated. Also, the code is not in the Update in the script I shared. Wouldn't creating another variable and instantiating it then spawn it twice?

Comment: GameObject objects = Instantiate(prefab[GetRandomSpawn()], transform.position, 
        Quaternion.identity);

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to be scaling the spawned objects.

Comment: I was thinking about another method, I updated my code again! Let me know if anything changes!

Comment: Correction, this scales the object, but only 1 spawned object. any that are spawned after revert to normal size.

Comment: I run into an error " Operator '*=' can not be applied to operands of type Vector3 and Vector3"

Comment: oops, I used *= with vector3, code edited.

Comment: Haha your are ok, I am learning quite a bit tonight. We have the object scaling, but it only scales one spawned object, and objects spawned after revert to the original scale again.

Comment: Ahah! it's ok, i do mistakes too, i edited the code

Comment: My apologies, these objects are being destroyed as the player collects them. I feel like this would of worked but I got this error. "The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if its null or you should not destroy the object".

Comment: Oh I see! I edited the code to take care of destroyed objects, let me know if it works!

Comment: So close! So this scales all currently spawned objects on the screen. However any newly spawned objects revert to the original scale. This also only reacts to the score one time. I have a score function in the Game Manager that will increase to 4, then reset to 0 and repeat. When this number hits 3 the scale of the game object reduces. then the number hits 4, goes back to 0, and repeats.

Comment: currentScore = GameManager.gameManager.repeatScore;

Comment: Gotcha! Then we update every frame... the ScaleSpawnedObjects method is called in every frame update if the currentScore meets the scaling condition. This ensures that all spawned objects, both existing and newly spawned, are consistently scaled.
Also, I've added the ResetSpawnPoint method to handle resetting the spawn point when the resetSpawnPoint reaches zero. You can customize the reset position as needed. Let me know if this does the trick!

Comment: Forgive me, The "resetSPawnPoint" method referenced to the X position of the empty Game object that held the object spawn script. I had the game object connected to a vector 3 of 0,0,0 because it was giving me some issues I needed to fix later. I had it reset to 20 on the X axis when the player would lose, therefore when the visible score in game went back to 0 the empty game object that holds the Object Spawner script would snap back to its original position.

Comment: The above code worked similar to the last edit, It changes the scale of all visible spawned objects, but any new spawned objects revert to the original scale, and the process is not repeated.

Comment: Alright, then I edited the code and moved the scaling logic to the Spawn method to scale the newly spawned objects and removed the objectScale flag and simplify the scaling process.

Comment: Even closer now! So with this script the scale is reducing all game objects that are spawned, as well as newly spawned. I am looking for the scale to happen every time the player gets 3 points. "currentScore = GameManager.gameManager.repeatScore;" tracks the amount of points the player has, then triggers the variable "recScore". Should I move to the update again?

Comment: Exactly, so I edited the code and moved scaling logic back to the Update method according to points!

Comment: So close, scale is happening, even with new spawns. Also, when the player gets 3 points. However, it is constantly scaling until it hits 0 and disappears completely. I attempted to add the "objectScale" bool to it to ensure it only scales one time every time the player gets 3 points but I don't think I placed it in the right place. I tried adding it to the update "if" statement that holds the "SCaleSpawnedObjects()" method but this stopped the newly spawned objects from scaling. So then I tried to add an if statement to the  "private void ScaleSpawnedObjects()" directly but this was incorrect.

Comment: The best way would be to flag with isScaling to track whether the scaling has been applied! I edited the code!

Comment: I noticed you added the "resetScale()" method to reset when the score hits 0. this is not intended. the score being tracked by "currentScore" is different than the visible score when playing the game. The "resetScale()" method would then use the "resetSpawnPoint = GameManager.gameManager.score;" variable as this tracks the visible score in game. If the player dies, the visible score resets to 0, therefore the scale resets to initial scale. Sorry my variable names may be confusing and need to be fixed.

Comment: Hmm, I think adding the isScaling bool stops the newly spawned objects from scaling as well.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I edited the code following your clarifications, does that work?

Comment: I feel like we are right there.

Comment: The bool is stopping the newly spawned objects from scaling.

Comment: Alright, then I edited removing the flag, it should work!

Comment: We have the newly spawned objects scaling again! But they are scaling every frame all the way to 0 until they disappear. Its like we need a bool somewhere, but if its in update it cuts off the newly spawned objects scale. I'm starting to think this may not be possible?

Comment: Alright so hold on, i reverted back to a flag method, tell me what happens now please so we can go from there

Comment: Scale happens when player hits required score, new spawned objects do not scale. If I try to hit another score of 3 after the first I get this error "InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Yes that's what i thought, my coroutine was messing up, ok so I edited the code and it should now work and fixed the error

Comment: Mike, thank you for all your time and effort tonight. I have been at this computer all day, and its almost 5 am. Well over 12 hours. I need get some sleep. Thank you again, so much, for all of your help. I will check back in a few hours when I wake up if you still want to continue on this journey.

Comment: OK, with this one, scale is happening on spawned objects, no scale on newly spawned objects. When player hits required score same error is triggered.

Comment: I will check back in a few hours, my eyes are killing me.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated after comments from OP***

Edited the script to use a `Getter/Setter` for the `currentScore` to simplify how the `scale` is updated and applied to new and active `objects`

```
// Target score before the scale is changed
private int targetScore = 3;
    
// var to hold the currentScore for use in the getter/setter
private int currentScore = 0;

// Getter/Setter for the currentScore that will update the objects scale if the currentScore reaches the targetScore before resetting the currentScore
private int CurrentScore
{
    get { return currentScore; }
    set
    {
        currentScore = value;

        if (currentScore == targetScore)
        {
            scale -= 0.1f * Vector3.one;

            for (int x = 0; x < objects.Count; x++)
            {
                objects[x].transform.localScale = scale;
            }

            currentScore = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Var for the current scale that will be modified in the Getter/Setter and can be used when spawning a new object
private Vector3 scale = Vector3.one;

// List of objects to loop through for scale changes
private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

// Simplified Spawn method that sets the current scale and adds it to the list for future updates
private void Spawn()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefab[GetRandomSpawn()], transform.position,Quaternion.identity);
    newObject.transform.position += Vector3.up * Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);
    newObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
    newObject.transform.localScale = scale;

    objects.Add(newObject);
}

// Usage
private void Update()
{
    if (DidWhateverItIsThatScores)
    {
        CurrentScore++;
    }
}
```

`Getter/Setters` are perfect for this for more info see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

*Note: You will want to clamp the scale so it has a minimum scale and doesn't go negative.*

Comment: The variable “currentScore” is tracking the method “repeatScore” within the Game manager script. In the game manager script the method “repeatScore” will increase to 4, then reset to 0 and repeat. So the idea was, in the object script when the repeatScore resets to 0 it would reset the bool “objectsScale”. I just notice that I have the variable “currentScore” that was connected to the GameManager singleton only in the update function. Could this be causing problems?

Comment: The end goal is to have the spawned objects scale down in size by a small amount every time the player gets 3 points. I can get the objects to scale, it’s the newly spawned objects that revert back to the original size.

Comment: I can not test yet but will look into this more later tonight! Thank you for your input!!

Comment: I have updated my question and it should be more clear!

Comment: I've updated my answer after reading your comments, it should now do what you are looking for in a much simplified way (left out code not directly related to the problem)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I will review the supporting documents and see if I can get it to work. I won’t be able to get to it for a few days but I think this will work.